# Regex to replace multiple instances of "tokens" in the following format: [[TokenName:TokenValue]]?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a Regex that can replace any instance of `[[Something:SomethingElse]]` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex: `\[\[.*?:.*?\]\]`

```
string str = @"some string before pattern [[Something:SomethingElse]] between
               pattern [[doesnt matter:at all]] after pattern";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[\[.*?:.*?\]\]", "");
```

Outout:

```
some string before pattern  between pattern  after pattern
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: you guys are fast ! : D

Comment: @Forlani - trying to :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.Replace and LookArounds:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?=\[\[)(.*?:.*?)(?<=\]\])", string.Empty);
```

Test case:

```
string value = "89as89d98as98d[[lksdlkfajks03:34]],[[939203902:ksadfjlkaklsdf]]9390290390ks";
```

Output:

```
value = "89as89d98as98d,9390290390ks"
```